# Oracle. Not able to return multiple Columns with Count

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble with a select statement.
I am getting the data of 3 columns from a products table(view) and everything is fine:

```
Select bin_number, part_number, qty
From Products V
Where Site = 'My_Site';
```

This gives me 5000+ rows.
The Problem is: The same part_number is in several different bins.

I have no problem getting the count on part_number:

```
Select part_number, COUNT(*)
FROM Products V
Where Site = 'My_Site'
Group By part_number
Having COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This returns 600 + rows of duplicate part_number(s) and how often they are duplicated, but I also need the bin_number and Qty columns.
Everything I've tried using the other two columns gives me an empty result set.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: To include those additional columns requires that you also return the additional rows since the values in those columns differ on each row. The concept of aggregation naturally involves some reduction of detail. There are 2+ bin_number and qty values for each part_number, as you pointed out, so if you're going to keep the lower row count, you would have to return the first or last of each, or something of the like, to aggregate.

Comment: try window functions for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Count Over()`

```
select * from 
(
Select bin_number, part_number, qty,count(1) over(partition by part_number) as cnt
From Products V
Where Site = 'My_Site'
)
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: This helps me determine which ones have duplicate, along with the other columns, but is there a way to return only those rows?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This will return parts that are in more than one bin.

```
Select part_number, COUNT(distinct bin_number)
FROM Products V
Where Site = 'My_Site'
Group By part_number
Having COUNT(distinct bin_number) > 1;
```